# Php header wont allow submission

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I am receiving the error message "Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in \WDP\DFS\46\8\7\8\4649635878\user\sites\1400094.site\www\MFPT2016\mfpt.php on line 54"

```
    <?php 

    $emailSubject = 'MFPT Submission';
    $webMaster = 'todd@treble-one.com';

    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $FirstName = $_REQUEST['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $_REQUEST['LastName'];
    $organization = $_REQUEST['organization'];
    $AddressLine2 = $_REQUEST['AddressLine2'];
    $City = $_REQUEST['City'];
    $StateProvince = $_REQUEST['StateProvince'];
    $Country = $_REQUEST['Country'];
    $ZipPostalCode = $_REQUEST['ZipPostalCode'];
    $Telephone = $_REQUEST['Telephone'];
    $Title = $_REQUEST['Title'];
    $WrittenPaper = $_REQUEST['WrittenPaper'];
    $Suggested_Conference_Session = $_REQUEST['Suggested_Conference_Session'];
    $Suggested_Conference_Track_Other = $_REQUEST['Suggested_Conference_Track_Other'];
    $CoAuthor = $_REQUEST['CoAuthor'];
    $Abstract = $_REQUEST['Abstract'];

    $body = <<<EOD

Email: $Email 
FirstName: $FirstName 
LastName: $LastName 
organization: $organization 
AddressLine1: $AddressLine1
AddressLine2: $AddressLine2
City: $City
StateProvince: $StateProvince
Country: $Country
ZipPostalCode: $ZipPostalCode
Telephone: $Telephone
Title: $Title
WrittenPaper: $WrittenPaper
Suggested_Conference_Session: $Suggested_Conference_Session 
Suggested_Conference_Track_Other: $Suggested_Conference_Track_Other
CoAuthor: $CoAuthor
Abstract: $Abstract
Comments: $Comments 
EOD;

 $host = "mail.treble-one.com";
 $username = "todd@treble-one.com";
 $password = "*******";

$headers .= 'From: Your name <mfpt@mfpt.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers = "Content=type: text/html\r\n";
$headers = "CC: $Email\r\n";


//line 54 
$success = mail ($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,$headers);



print " Thank you for you inquiry we will be in touch shortly.";

?>
```

`

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue with the headers that I see is that first, you append to $headers before it is set, then you reassign it twice.

```
$headers .= 'From: Your name <mfpt@mfpt.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers = "Content=type: text/html\r\n";
$headers = "CC: $Email\r\n";
```

Should be:

```
$headers = 'From: Your name <mfpt@mfpt.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content=type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: $Email\r\n";
```